# VB.Net search for new occurencies of value in datatable

Tags: vb.net, search, datatable

I'm trying to search one datatable for a string, so if new hits are appeared the action is triggered. How to do that?

My current code:

```
If searchvalue <> "" Then
                foundRows = table.Select("Name LIKE '%" & searchvalue & "%'")
                If foundRows.Length = 0 Then
                    'none found
                Else
                    For Each r In foundRows
                        notif("Found "&r.itemarray(0) & " in " & r.itemarray(1))
                    Next
                End If
            End If
```

the "notif" function is called for every hit each time the sub is called; but i want it to be called once for every unique hit. How to do it?

Using case: say, first time sub is called when table is like that:

```
something foo
smthelse bar
```

the search string is "some", the Notif called once for "something foo". Next time the sub is called table is like that:

```
something foo
something else 
smthelse bar
```

Now Notif should be called only for "something else"

Comment: Is "something" a field and "foo" another or is "something foo" one field?

Comment: something foo = one row, two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - i used the row.RowState property.

Each time the row is changed or added, its row.RowState property equals either DataRowState.Added or DataRowState.Modified, and when the row.AcceptChanges() called it becomes DataRowState.Unchanged .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `Linq-To-DataSet` instead which makes your code more readable, maintainable and also has some nice features like grouping:

```
If searchvalue.Length <> 0 Then
    Dim foundNamegroups = From row In table
                          Let Name = row.Field(Of String)("Name")
                          Where Name.Contains(searchvalue)
                          Group row By Name Into NameGroup = Group
    If foundNamegroups.Any() Then
        For Each grp In foundNamegroups
            ' note that the DataRows are in  grp.NameGroup
            Dim msg = String.Format("Found {0} rows for name {1}", grp.NameGroup.Count(), grp.Name)
            notif(msg)
        Next
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Sorry, but how to use it for multiple searching? Like, i got a datatable of values to search, and i need to do something like "Where Name.Contains(searchtable.rows(1)(0).formattedvalue) OR Name.Contains(searchtable.rows(2)(0).formattedvalue) OR ... Name.Contains(searchtable.rows(searchtable.rows.count)(0).formattedvalue)